# Illustrator CS6 how to "flatten path"?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've made a paisley flower shape and I'd like it to have a transparent fill, the issue is if the layers are transparent then you can see the shapes behind. is there a way to flatten or combine the paths?

[image]

[image]

Hopefully the images make it clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select all
- `Object > Expand Appearance` (if available)
- `Object > Expand`
- Click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** (Window > Pathfinder)

Note that this will expand all strokes to filled shapes. If you need to retain strokes as strokes, the the Shape Builder Tool may be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Make a transparency mask to the back group of objects:

[image]

- Copy the top object
- Select the back object and group it
- From the **Transparency Panel** click the **Make Mask** button and uncheck Clip
- Click the Transparency Panel Mask area (the right square)
- Past in front <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Win
- Fill the pasted object 100% black
- Click the Transparency Panel Edit area (the left square)

[image: Mask]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the shape builder tool is your friend for stuff like this: copy all these paths into a new flattened layer so you keep your original undestroyed - shape builder is a destructive workflow.